# sencha touch > phonegap > android 3.1 Acer A500 web page contains error

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have deployed android application made with sencha touch and phonegap,
and I don't have any problem with classic smartphone.

But with an ACER A500 on Android 3.1, a user have a problem :

```
"Application Error
 The Web page contains an error. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html#false&en)"
```

## false&en is my method for passed android variable preference to js.

after i split this.

The problem is when I use emulator (android 3.1) I don't have any error.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

See [this Android issue ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327). It seems that URL's with the file protocol and parameters cause the problem in Android version > 3.0.

For example `file://android_asset/index.html` can be loaded OK, but

`file://android_asset/index.html?dddd`
or
`file://android_asset/index.html#dddd`

gives an error, regardless of notifying character ?, #, or whatever.

Interestingly, simulators does not spit out errors.